# Invoke-Command wrapper function that passes Cmdlet name and parameters

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I am building an Azure Runbook helper function, that ultimately executes on a Hybrid Runbook Worker.

To generalize my code as much as possible I came up with the idea to have a function dynamically build a scriptblock that defines the Exchange Cmdlet name and parameter.This is what I have so far - the comments are experiments that reveal some of the steps I tried before posting this thread.

```
function Invoke-BSExchangeCommand{
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $CmdletName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [hashtable]
    $ArgumentList,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession]
    $Session
)

$scriptBlock = {
    param ($invokeParams)
    # Get-DistributionGroup @invokeParams
    # $_::$CmdletName.Invoke($invokeParams)
    $cmd = Get-Command -Name $CmdletName
    & $cmd @invokeParams
}

$params = @{
    Session      = $Session
    ArgumentList = $ArgumentList
    ScriptBlock  = $scriptBlock
}

Invoke-Command @params
}
```

Edit: I have found that the "Get-Command" cmdlet is exposed/not restricted on the Exchange endpoint.

The error I am getting is a generic one and gives many different (irrelevant) Google search results: *A Begin statement block, Process statement block, or parameter statement is not allowed in a Data section*

Edit: My starting point that I am trying to improve is that this scriptblock with the defined Cmdlet name works:

```
$scriptBlock = {
    param ($invokeParams)
    Get-DistributionGroup @invokeParams
}
```

Thank you!

-Anders

Comment: `$CmdletName` won't carry through the session, you need `$using:CmdletName` in the scriptblock; but I doubt that's the cause of your error. [DATA sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_data_sections?view=powershell-6) are restricted parts of the language where you can't inject potentially risky code, for security, only pass data / limited code through. I guess this is happening somewhere in the Runbook -> Runbook Worker -> Exchange restricted session. Is it Office 365 Exchange or on-premises?

Comment: The "$using:" approach is not working in this environment (I am an external consultant btw), hence I am using the older "-Argumentlist" approach. 
It's On Premise (this happens in a Hybrid runbook worker Powershell session)
I made a typo, so I renamed the $CmdletName variable name to $cmd